# How to Find Max Average and Lowest value in knapsack problem

Tags: knapsack-problem

1. Our basket will hold a weight of 1000. Using a random number generator, generate 100 possible items for the basket. The items should have random weights between 1 and 300.
2. Use the dynamic programming algorithm to compute the exact optimal solution for the set of 100 items. Note that the solution is a weight, wj, where 0 < wj < 1000.
3. Use the greedy approximation algorithm to compute an approximate solution using the same set of items.
4. Run this set of steps 10 times, keeping track of the high, low and average values. Also, keep track of the running times for both algorithms.

This project requires a track of high, low and average values and is should contain a table with your experimental results:

```
    Dynamic(Exact)  Greedy(Approx.) Approximation Factor
```

Highest
Average
Lowest

```
package knapsack;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Muhammad Ali Ghaffar
 */
public class Knapsack {

    public int max(int a, int b){
        return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }

    public int min(int a, int b){
        return (a < b) ? a : b;
    }


    public int KSKMAX(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n) 
    { 
        int i, w; 
        int K[][] = new int[n + 1][W + 1]; 

        for (i = 0; i<= n; i++) { 
            for (w = 0; w<= W; w++) { 
                if (i == 0 || w == 0) 
                    K[i][w] = 0; 
                else if (wt[i - 1]<= w) 
                    K[i][w] = max(val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]); 
                else
                    K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w]; 
            } 
        } 

        return K[n][W]; 
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Knapsack k1=new Knapsack();
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomvalues = rand.nextInt(100);

        int val[] = new int[100]; 
        int wt[] = new int[1000]; 

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            val[i]=rand.nextInt(100)+1;

        }



        int W = rand.nextInt(300); 
        int n = val.length;
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("| Highest :"+k1.KSKMAX(W, wt, val, n)+"  |");
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("| Average :"+k1.KSKMAX(W, wt, val, n)+"  |");
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println("| Lowest  :"+k1.KSKLOW(W, wt, val, n)+"  |");
        System.out.println("----------------");

    }

}
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: updated please read again

Comment: i repeat what i said, what problem are you having with the code you posted ?

Comment: above code is just gives me Higest value but I also want average and minimum value

Comment: In that case can you edit your question to make that clear please